# does gradle support excluding source files only for some flavor/buildtype when there is multiple flavor/type?

Tags: android, gradle

my source tree:

```
app/src/main/java/com/example/A.java
app/src/main/java/com/example/B.java
```

I want to customizing some specific build using productFlavor or buildType.
But I find that exclude statement in sourceSets affects other productFlavor/buildType too.

**example** 1.

```
productFlavors {
    full {
        sourceSets {
            main {
                java {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    mini {
        sourceSets {
            main {
                java {
                    exclude '**/A.java'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after build, both

```
  app-mini-release.aar
```

and

```
  app-full-release.aar
```

are the same.

**example** 2:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true 
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }

    debug {
        sourceSets {
            main {
                java {
                    exclude '**/A.java'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after build, both

```
app-debug.aar
```

and

```
app-release.aar
```

contains A.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your A.java file to `app/src/full/java/com/example/` from `app/src/main/java/com/example/`

After that if you select miniDebug in build variants it will exclude the files from

> app/src/full/*

Comment: I don't want to separate source files into main other directory A and B should be in the same package which makes more sense for me.

Comment: The build merges your packeges, so they won't be in different packeges, you just separate it for the builder. Check the link https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors "You should structure additional sourceset directories exactly like the main/ sourceset, except that the name of the root directory must exactly match the name of the build type, product flavor, or build variant it belongs to."